# Would we face any roadblocks when we implement a CI/ CD flow using Heroku, if we have deployed Selenium + Java for Test automation?

Tags: selenium

Can you please tell me ,Would we face any roadblocks when we implement a CI/ CD flow using Heroku, if we have deployed Selenium + Java for Test automation mechanism

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any such known issues or roadblocks implementing a CI/ CD flow using Heroku if you have deployed Selenium and Java for Test automation mechanism.

However, issues cropping out in real time implementation may be subjective to deep dives and subsequent analysis.